# How to give access to view all unpublished comment for any role?

Tags: 7, views, users, comments

I have a one `role` forum admin. This role manage the all comment `published/unpublished`.

To manage I have created the `comment view` and listed all published or unpublished comment.

My issue is when forum admin click on published comment it's showing but when he click on unpublished comment the comment not showing.

I want to view also unpublished comment to forum admin role.
How can give this permission to forum admin role.

Comment: Which Version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I am Using Drupal 7.38